# ImportError: No module named 'geocoder'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use geocoder in a Notebook in IBM Watson but when I run import geocoder it returns

```
"ImportError: No module named 'geocoder'
```

Is there anyone with the same issue who has found a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why are you convinced that this module should exist on your computer?

Comment: well, it is a python module and I am trying to use with a Python notebook. Worked it out now, rather dumb of me- I hadn't previously installed geocoder:) works ok now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use a module it needs to be installed on your computer, some common ones will already be installed, but goecoder is not as far as I know.
Have you already tried to download the

```
pip install geocoder
```

**Windows users who forgot to add pip to path** might want to try this instead:

```
python -m pip install geocoder
```

Comment: indeed mate, tried that earlier and worked fine, thanks!